# Is it possible to create computer macros (keyboard events and such) using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, macros, automation, autohotkey

I could not find useful results because of confusion with programming macros (like where Lisp shines). Can you configure computer macros such as 'send key input to a window' using JavaScript?

Comment: If the code is running in the browser then the macros would be limited to the page that the macro is contained within. i.e. Don't expect to be able to control your PC/Mac from javascript inside a browser

Comment: I was expecting it to be possible with help of a Java applet, but I guess that was not done yet, then.

Comment: Java and Javascript are not the same thing. If the Java is running inside the browser then pretty sure you'll have the same limitations.

Comment: [Project SIKULI](http://sikuli.org/) uses Jython; perhaps it would be possible to adapt it to use Rhino JavaScript, since both are JVM languages.

Answer (score 1):

Child windows can call functions from its parent or opener window. So you can mimic this behavior by creating functions on the parent window like

```
function acceptKey(val) {
   alert(val);
}
```

then on the child window you can call the function

```
window.parent.acceptKey("Test"); // If iframe
//or if new window
window.opener.acceptKey("Test2");
```

On windows not related to each other then no.